# Rotas no Angular 1.6

Tags: angularjs, angular-routes

Sou iniciante em angular. Minhas rotas não carregam na ng-view. Quando clico no link minha url fica da seguinte forma

> http://localhost:56845/Index.html#Add
>   e nada acontece.

Nenhum erro é exibido no console.

Utilizo o angular 1.6.

test.js

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngRoute']);

MyApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $routePriveder.
        when('/add', {
            templateUrl: 'Paginas/add.html',
            controller: 'AddController'

        }).
        when('/edit', {
            templateUrl: 'paginas/edit.html',
            controller: 'EditController'
        }).
        when('/delete', {
            templateUrl: 'paginas/delete.html',
            controller: 'DeleteController'
        }).
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'paginas/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        }); 
});
```

controllers.js

```
MyApp.controller("AddController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg= "Add";

});

MyApp.controller("EditController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "Editar";
});

MyApp.controller("DeleteController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg= "deletar";
});
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
     <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="container-fluid">
               <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> O que Tem Pra Hj? </a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#add">Add</a><li>
                    <li><a href="#edit">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#delete">Delete</a></li>
                </ul>
         </div>
     </nav>

    <div ng-view>  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

add.html

```
 <h2 ng-controller="AddController">{{msg}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua versão precisa de algumas pequenas correções antes de funcionar.

- `$routePriveder` parece ser um erro de digitação (`$routeProvider`)
- `HomeController` é especificado na declaração de rotas, porém nunca é declarado. Solução: implemente `HomeController`
- *Controllers* são especificados para cada uma das declarações de rotas, porém a view `add.html` força o carregamento de `AddController` uma segunda vez. Solução: Remova a menção da view

O seu código é funcional após as modificações necessárias:

```js
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngRoute']);

MyApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $routeProvider.
        when('/add', {
            templateUrl: 'templateCRUD.html',
            controller: 'AddController'
        }).
        when('/edit', {
            templateUrl: 'templateCRUD.html',
            controller: 'EditController'
        }).
        when('/delete', {
            templateUrl: 'templateCRUD.html',
            controller: 'DeleteController'
        }).
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'templateCRUD.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        }); 
});

MyApp.controller("HomeController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg= "Home";
});

MyApp.controller("AddController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg= "Adicionar";
});

MyApp.controller("EditController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "Editar";
});

MyApp.controller("DeleteController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg= "deletar";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateCRUD.html">
    <h2>{{msg}}</h2>
</script>

<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> O que Tem Pra Hj? </a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#add">Add</a></li>
                <li><a href="#edit">Edit</a></li>
                <li><a href="#delete">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div ng-view>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente colocar no Head do index.html

```
<base href="/">
```

procure usar sempre letras minusculas nas rotas.

/add  e não /Add

Remova o

```
$locationProvider 
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');


 MyApp.config(function($routeProvider) { 
    $routeProvider
      .when... 
 });
```

Comment: agora não localizou e minha url ficou da seguinte forma
http://localhost:56845/#Add

Comment: Você trocou as rotas para minusculo ? Se sim faltou trocar também nos href="#add"

Comment: Sim, editei a pergunta para tudo minusculo tb.

Comment: Remova o 
`$locationProvider ` e `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('')` Editei minha resposta para visualizar melhor.

Comment: mesmo erro anterior, não localizou.

Comment: Você está acessando /index.html tente acessar apenas

http://localhost:56845

Comment: Verifique também se sua pǵina de templates esta correta, Paginas e não paginas

Comment: Alterei para paginas e ao tentar acessar pelo localhost:56845 da erro: Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.

Comment: Como você está rodando o aplicativo ? Deveria estar funcionando, veja esse exemplo simples do w3c, aqui eles nem precisaram adicionar base url.
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

Comment: Fiz pelo visual studio, rodo utilizando o IIS.